# How to trace the mouse focus event in javascript or AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, focus, autofocus

I have a weird bug in my web application. Say, I have two input box on my page: **Input-A** and **Input-B**.

When I focus on **Input-A**, and when there is a somewhat event triggered, the **focus** will jump to **Input-B**. However, I didn't write any code to change the **focus**. The event also has nothing to do with **focus changing**, at least I didn't find it.

Therefore, I'm wondering if there is anyway to find out who trigger the **focus** to change. Or, can I trace the **focus** event?

I use JavaScript and AngularJS and Firebase.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are using HTML5 then use autofocus attribute.

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509032/how-to-debug-javascript-events-or-how-to-make-all-functions-call-trace