# Kendo UI TreeView context-right click confuses selection

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui

Below I've tried to simplify more complex TreeView usage, where I'm failing to implement a ContextMenu on TreeView node items, into a fiddle that exhibits potentially related issues. Steps: In my simplified example one left clicks to select a node, then right clicks on another node, and finally dismisses with escape, and then selection indications are confused. I've tried "return false", select(nothing), and preventDefault() to no avail.

My question is: is this a bug in Kendo UI, or am I missing something in my usage of TreeView?

https://jsfiddle.net/3cp9m8wo/

```
<div id='Tree_Space'></div>
<script type='text/x-kendo-template' id='Tree_template'>
    #= item.Name#
</script>
<script>
    $('#Tree_Space').kendoTreeView({
        dataSource: [ { Name: 'Top', items: [ { Name:'Item' }, { Name:'Item' } ] } ],
        template: kendo.template($('#Tree_template').html())
    });
    $("#Tree_Space").data("kendoTreeView").expand('.k-item');
</script>
```

My full goal would be to disable Kendo UI selection on TreeView nodes completely, allowing me to implement left clicks (actions) and right clicks (ContextMenus) for elements I placed within tree nodes. However, I've not seen a way to disable select on TreeView. I do find JQuery.click() does seem to work and deselect Kendo UI selections, but Kendo UI Context Menu fails to popup on right click, and displays other artifacts - one of which I think I've isolated here in hopes of learning something.

Comment: I haven't tried this but you could search for disabling an html element. and apply that to the Parent nodes. It probably has something to do with mousedown(). However, you will have to create a client template for your nodes and add something like a parent node style 'no-click' and then apply your disable element code to all items of 'no-click'.

Comment: @lrb Thanks for the idea. It's outside my wheelhouse at this point, but I will start reading and digging and see what I can make of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try using something in your template to control this:

```
   <script type='text/x-kendo-template' id='Tree_template'>
        //Ideally, your server will return a collection that determines if the item can be selected, likewise, you could add a IsParentNode or something to indicate the item should be treated differently. 
        #if (item.CanSelect != 'null' && item.CanSelect==true)  { #
            <span>#: item.Name#</span>    
        #}else{#
            <span class='no-select'>#: item.Name#</span>    
        #}#   
   </script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
       $(document).ready(function () {
           //Add code here to tie into the onmousedown of all .no-select elements

            $(document).on("click", "no-select", function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();                   
            });
       });
  </script>
```

Comment: your response convinces me my fiddle touches a Kendo UI bug/oversight, not that I am missing something. Moreover, thanks to your comments combined with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3509032 I was able examine event handlers, trace back source, then walk through Kendo UI code and find patches to click and mousedown. With my resulting partial hack to avoid context menus messing selection at https://jsfiddle.net/acc1ka1g, I then find this was not my entire problem (context menus work in the simple case). But, with the new info and tool I'm sure I'll work it out now. Thanks again!

Comment: I ran into this exact same issue several months ago using Kendo treeview, so it's definitely not just you.  You should open a support ticket with them if you can, maybe we can get a fix for it.